# Google API for android crashed and I doing any thing right

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to develop some app with Google Maps API.

I'm followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) step by step and the app crashed!

I tried so many tutorials, even [this one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2), but I get always the same error:

```
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemaps/com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    ... 11 more
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4132500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.eb(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4965)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
05-18 00:53:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(17073):    ... 21 more
```

Can someone help?

Comment: `You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` --> Do you have this in your Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes . but it still not working

Comment: Try adding this to manifest..`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4132500" />`

Comment: It's works!!! tnx :) but what the reason was?!

Comment: I dont know the correct reason for that..Ive added that as my answer..Could you please mark it as accepted...

Comment: I think its due to the mismatch in google play services version...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace `@integer/google_play_services_versio`n with `4132500`

see this

**google-play-services_lib --> res --> values --> version.xml**

for the correct version of your google play services